# Python/Jupyter notebook in VSCode does not use the right environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, windows-10, ipython

## The situation

I use Anaconda 3 on Windows 10.

I have a Visual Studio Code workspace (`my_workspace`) than contains a Jupyter notebook (`my_notebook.ipynb`). VSCode has the Python extension installed.

The file `my_workspace/settings.json` contains:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Me\\Anaconda3\\envs\\my_env\\python.exe"
}
```

`my_env` is an existing Anaconda environment. I can activate it and work with it in a shell, and if I run `jupyter lab` in such a shell, the code inside the notebooks can import `my_env`'s packages as expected.

If I open `my_workspace` in VSCode, then `my_notebook.ipynb` in a tab, `my_env` is also mentioned in VSCode's status bar ("Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('my_env': conda)"), and `my_env` is automatically activated when I open a PowerShell prompt in VSCode's console (I ran `conda init` once).

## The problem

When the notebook is opened in VSCode, the Jupyter kernel seems to use the `base` environment's Python interpreter instead of the one in `my_env`. When importing a package installed in `my_env`, but not in `base`, I get this error:

```
>>> import keras
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

This happens for all packages, not just `keras`.

In the notebook tab in VSCode, if I click on the interpreter's name in the top-right corner, then choose the correct interpreter (the one in `my_env`), then the notebook runs correctly in `my_env`. But I have to do this every time I re-open VSCode.

How to make the default kernel respect the environment chosen in `settings.json`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think there is no parameter right now to control that in the `settings.json`. I had similar problems with the environments in which the notebook is launched and I was able to fix this modifying the `kernelspec` section in the IPython notebook.

Basically, open the notebook as a JSON file and remove the `kernelspec` section. When the notebook is launched from vscode, that part will be filled with the default python environment kernel for the workspace. In my case, is filled with the pipenv environment.

Comment: We  (I work on the extension) try to use the kernelspec in the notebook if it's there. So if the kernelspec references a valid kernel, we'll use that to start the IPython kernel under the covers. Unfortunately as @pablosjv noticed, this doesn't use your selected python environment. It literally just runs the python specified in the kernel.json as if you started it from an empty command shell. However if you erase the kernelspec from the notebook, we'll instead generate a new kernelspec that matches the environment you have selected in VS code. That's why pablosjv fix works.

Comment: strangely, this also works for c# notebooks! a "language-agnostic" solution should definitely have a special badge.

Comment: @RChiodo VSCode Jupyter & Python are wonderful extensions but I think this behavior can be improved by explicitly letting the user know which kernel interpreter it is using. I had to dig around for a while to find out why `import torch` was not working on VSCode's Jupyter when it worked just fine on the native Jupyter env.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this helps, but maybe not. I ran into this issue during a ssh session on a remote machine. I had to use the VS code command > Python: Select Interpreter

[image: > Python: Select Interpreter]

form here I needed to add the location to the environment I wished to work form.

[image: add path]

so long as jupyter is installed in the path there should be no issues (:

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after creating the new Environment the VS Code had to be relaunched several times and then it found the new env. It looked as if VS Code had to take some time to find the new Env in the system.