# Jupyter uses the wrong Python version in code cell shell commands

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook

So basically, I am using a package online that requires the use of the shell in order to parse data. The line of code that needs to be sent to the shell is as follows:

`python scripts/extract.py esm2_t33_650M_UR50D data/output.fasta data/output_esm --repr_layers 33 --include per_tok`

Where `extract.py` contains a Python script that needs to be run.

In order to achieve this, I had to utilize the `!` in the code cell in order to send the line of code to the shell.

However, running the code cell returned an invalid syntax error:

```
File "scripts/extract.py", line 79
    print(f"Read {args.fasta_file} with {len(dataset)} sequences")
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Looking online, it seemed this was caused by the `f""` functionality not being available in Python 2.x versions. Which is weird since [I am currently running Jupyter on Python 3.8.13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNI2H.png).

So I checked the version of Python through the shell and [realized it was still running on Python 2.7.17](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNPGk.png)

How do I tell the shell explicitly to use Python 3.x interpreter and packages instead of 2.x? I was always under the assumption that the shell would use the same version of Python that Jupyter is running on.

Thank you!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60497198 answer your question?

Comment: Also, you aren't using Jupyter in the way it is meant. To run a Python script from inside a notebook, you'll have better support and features using `%run` magic, see [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-run). In fact you can insure it even runs in the same namespace as the current notebook by adding the `-i` flag. So that any variables you've assigned in the current running notebook will be accessible by the script. This is very helpful when developing a script or debugging. About your assumption, see the second paragraph ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/location-of-libraries-or-extensions-installed-in-jupyterlab/16303/2?u=fomightez). Possible issues with where things run when using the exclamation point is also related to why you should **now** use the magic install commands if you ever install packages from inside your running notebook using `pip` or `conda`, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez).